# Generalization of optimality of Grover's algorithm for an arbitrary number of marked elements

Tags: grovers-algorithm

In the final remark [Zalka's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9711070.pdf) about the proof of exact optimality of Grover's algorithm for the search problem with a single marked state, we have the following suggestion for future work:

> "I have here only considered oracles with the promise that there is exactly one marked element. It seems very plausible that the proof can be extended to oracles with any known(!) number of marked elements".

Has this already been done? Be it a generalization of Zalka's proof or even a different proof. I'm trying to find it, but so far, nothing.

Comment: Since you have found your answer, instead of editing it into the question, you should put it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. For anyone interested, it's the Lemma 2 from [Hamann Dunjko and Wölk paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42484-021-00049-7)